# Google Maps on a Windows Store App (C#/XAML) - No pinch zoom

Tags: google-maps-api-3, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Has anyone been able to successfully include some sort of Google Maps view on a Windows Store App (C#/XAML) for **Windows 8.1**? We have opted for Google Maps due to the cost of the Bing Maps license (which would be much easier as there is a native Metro control for Bing Maps).

I was able to follow [this article](http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/) and include an html page inside a WebView control. I can also communicate to and from it with my C# class (using **ScriptNotify** and **window.external.notify**).

**However, the pinch-zoom gesture is not being recognized as it doesn't perform zoom on the map.**

Here is my WebView

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="GridOut">
        <WebView x:Name="MapWebView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ManipulationMode="All" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And the html page with the map:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> <!-- To get double tap for zoom to work-->
    <!– Google Maps API reference –>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/richmarker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CountryInfo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/infobox.js"></script>
    <!– map references –>
    <link href="map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapdisplay" />
</body>
</html>
```

*However, if I open my HTML page inside IE (even using IE inside the Visual Studio Simulator) the Pinch-to-zoom gesture is there and works smoothly, so I assume that the problem is with the WebView. On the other hand, if I navigate my WebView to this [URL](https://maps.google.com), pinch zoom will work, so this really has me baffled.*

I have also tried:

1) Using an IFrame inside an extra HTML page but it didn't change anything.

2) Implement my own JavaScript Gesture recognizer for zoom (with MSGestureChange) but the result is far from desirable and I feel like I'm "reinventing a very bad wheel"...

Has anyone com across this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing to try may be adding [-ms-content-zooming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441251.aspx) to your map script.

Comment: Hello Nate. Thanks for the suggestion. I applied on the CSS for the document body and the actual Map div, but I didn't notice any difference. No zoom. I don't understand why the pinch zoom works fine on a regular browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may be out of luck. WebView isn't a full browser, it only renders pages in Document Mode. What you may need to do is add a Gesture recognizers, as you suggested. You can however, do this in C#/Xaml and then use the ScriptNotify to instruct the JavaScript what to do. This will also make it a bit easier to debug/test.

Comment: Thanks again, Nate. I actually handled the Pinch Gesture directly on the JavaScript to avoid having to re-implement all other gestures (Drag for pan, double-tap etc...). I posted my solution below, strangely though, multi-touch can be captured inside the actual WebView, which leads me to believe this could be something with the Google Maps v3 api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I got working, but it is far from the actual Google Maps zoom, because:

1) Google Maps' pinch-to-zoom doesn't simply jump to a zoom-level, it scales the tiles as well for a smooth animation/transition.

2) Depending where the user applies the zoom on the screen, it will tend to pan into that area as well (suppose you are centered on LatLong 0, 0, with zoom-level 2. If the user pinches on the North Pole, the zoom-level should increase and gradually pan towards the North Pole as you keep zooming in).

```
var mGesture = new MSGesture();

function InitGestureHandler()
{

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapdisplay');
    mGesture.target = mapDiv;

    // You need to first register to MSPointerDown to be able to
    // have access to more complex Gesture events
    mapDiv.addEventListener("pointerdown", pointerdown, false);
    mapDiv.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", manipulateElement, false);

}

function manipulateElement(e) {

    //Can also add timestamps here to allow the code to run only every so milliseconds
    if (e.scale > 1.05) {
        map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
    }
    else if (e.scale < 0.95) {
        map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Google is aware of the pinch-to-zoom issue on Windows 8.1 but they did not fix it yet. You might want to upvote the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5747